# QDialog::exec react after 3 calls

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using a custom dialog, and I'm showing it by calling:

```
this->numberPick.move(point);
this->numberPick.setWindowFlags(Qt::SplashScreen);
this->numberPick.setParent(this);
this->numberPick.setModal(true);
this->numberPick.exec();
```

All this code is invoked in `void MainWindow::on_boardView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index){}` (event "clicked" from `QTableView`).

The problem is quite strange. I need to click on my button for 3 times for dialog to show. After second click Qt Creator gives me warning like this `"QDialog::exec: Recursive call detected"`.

Funny thing is that this happens only once (in single application instance). Next clicks works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fixed this problem, but i made a little workaround and it works like that:

```
this->numberPick = new NumberPick(this);
this->numberPick->setCell(cell);
this->numberPick->move(point);
this->numberPick->setWindowFlags(Qt::SplashScreen);
this->numberPick->exec();
delete this->numberPick;
```

But the question is still opened